# I'm trying to understand these errors in the code blocks

Tags: c++

```
    Stack::Stack(const Stack& copy)
{
    Stack temp;
    copyHelper(copy.top, temp);


}
void Stack::copyHelper(Node* top, Stack newStack) {
    if (top != nullptr)
    {
        copyHelper(top->getNext(), newStack);
        newStack.push(top->getPayload());
    }
}
```

I'm getting three errors related to the code block above:

Error   C2600   'Stack::Stack': cannot define a compiler-generated special member function (must be declared in the class first)    Program5    C:\Users\tcran\source\repos\Program5\Program5\Stack.cpp 14

Error   C2264   'Stack::Stack': error in function definition or declaration; function not called    Program5    C:\Users\tcran\source\repos\Program5\Program5\Stack.cpp 16

Error   C2264   'Stack::Stack': error in function definition or declaration; function not called    Program5    C:\Users\tcran\source\repos\Program5\Program5\Stack.cpp 23

Can someone please elaborate on why I am getting this errors?

Comment: The shown code fails meets all requirements of a [mre], as explained in stackoverflow.com's [help]. Until it does it's unlikely that anyone will be able to help you. For more information, see [ask] questions.

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
class Stack
{
public:

  // this constructor has not been specified in your class definition.
  Stack(const Stack& copy);
};
```

Comment: How about this block:     
 Stack& Stack::operator=(Stack& copy)
 {
  Node* temp = copy.top;
  while (top != nullptr)
  {
   pop();
  }
   copyHelper(copy.top);
  
 }  Whaat should it be returning?

Comment: ....   return *this;